# Can send two emails individually but not together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a real humdinger of a problem. If I run the following on the console

```
> ExpiringCatalogEntriesMailer.notify_expiring_catalog_entries(self, nil).deliver
> ExpiringCatalogEntriesMailer.notify_expiring_catalog_entries(self, 'MarketingAdminUser').deliver
```

it sends TWO emails, which is what I want. However, when I invoke this function on the console

```
def send_catalog_expiration_emails
  ExpiringCatalogEntriesMailer.notify_expiring_catalog_entries(self, nil).deliver
  ExpiringCatalogEntriesMailer.notify_expiring_catalog_entries(self, 'MarketingAdminUser').deliver
end
```

it only sends the first of the two emails and not the second.

Why might this be?

(I'm using Rails 4.1.14.)

Comment: Can you comment the first line and then invoke the function again? And what are you seeing now?

Comment: Good idea. When I do that, it sends the second email. So it looks like the presence of the first line is preventing the second line from working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The [mail-logger](https://github.com/joshmcarthur/mail-logger) gem was installed, and when the first email was sending, it was looking for a certain log file which didn't exist. I removed mail-logger and the problem went away.